osmnx python network_type filters
I am getting familiar with the package and I have been trying to find a list of all the possible custom filters for network_type.
Looking directly at the code has provided some ideas, but I wonder if there is a list somewhere with all the type of filters (motorway, primary, residential) per network_type (drive, walking,bike)

The list of available filters is provided in each of these functions' documentation https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#module-osmnx.graph

Here is a link to all the types of filters road network analysis and OpenStreetMap Wiki.
The network_type parameter allows you to specify the type of network (e.g., driving, walking, biking). Each network_type includes a predefined set of OSM highway tags.
1. drive
Included Highway Types:

motorway, motorway_link
trunk, trunk_link
primary, primary_link
secondary, secondary_link
tertiary, tertiary_link
unclassified, residential
living_street, service

import osmnx as ox

# Fetch driving network
G = ox.graph_from_place('Your Location', network_type='drive')

2. drive_service
Included Highway Types:

All types in drive
Additional minor service roads

G = ox.graph_from_place('Your Location', network_type='drive_service')


3. bike
Included Highway Types:

cycleway
primary, primary_link
secondary, secondary_link
tertiary, tertiary_link
unclassified, residential
living_street, service
path, road, track

G = ox.graph_from_place('Your Location', network_type='bike')


4. walk
Included Highway Types:

footway, pedestrian
path, steps
residential, living_street
service
cycleway, road (for crossings and walkways)

G = ox.graph_from_place('Your Location', network_type='walk')


5. all
Included Highway Types:

Major Roads: motorway, trunk, primary, etc.
Local Roads: unclassified, residential, service, etc.
Pedestrian Paths: footway, pedestrian, path, etc.
Others: cycleway, steps, track, bridleway, raceway, busway, etc.

G = ox.graph_from_place('Your Location', network_type='all')


6. all_private
Included Highway Types:

All types in all
Private roads and paths not typically public

G = ox.graph_from_place('Your Location', network_type='all_private')

You can use a Custom filter
highway_types = [
    'motorway', 'trunk', 'primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'residential', 'unclassified',
    'motorway_link', 'trunk_link', 'primary_link', 'secondary_link', 'tertiary_link',
    'living_street', 'service', 'road'
]

 
custom_filter = '["highway"~"{}"]'.format('|'.join(highway_types))

G = ox.graph_from_place('Your Location', custom_filter=custom_filter)


Hi! This is great, thank you for your answer! Maybe a short follow up, have you had any experience querying the road structure of an entire country? This type of query inevitably surpasses the Overpass max query area and I find to be too time consuming

You are welcome, you can divide it into small regions. Please see this

In case helpful; filters are also listed at source in the function:
def _get_network_filter in _overpass.py :
https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/main/osmnx/_overpass.py

Yes I saw that! Thanks! I did find it to be a bit incomplete though.
